# R: substitue and execution environments

Tags: r, environment

I am currently writing a function that will take an equation as an argument. The function will expect variables to be apart of the column names of data.

```
mydata <- data.frame(x=c(1,2,3,4),y=c(5,6,7,8), z=c(9,10,11,12))
my_function <- function(data, equ) {
 EQU.sub <- deparse(substitute(equ))
 #Check if colnames are used
 for(i in 1:length(colnames(data)) {
   if(str_detect(string = EQU.sub, pattern = colnames(data)[i])) {
    #if used, create variable with its name.
    assign(x = colnames(data)[i],
         value = eval(parse(text = paste("data$",
                                         colnames(data),
                                         sep = ""))))
   } else {
     warning(paste(colnames[i], "was not used in EQU"))
   }
  }
df$new.value <- eval(equ)
output <- function(new.equ = equ)
return(df)
}

my_function(data = mydata, equ = x+(y^2))
```

I know what you may be thinking, this is a big workaround for just doing
`mydata$x+(mydata$y^2)`

**THE ISSUE**

The issue is that I want to pass my input of equ into an new function.

```
new_function <- function(new.equ) { 
string <- deparse(substitute(new.equ))
#does some stuff....
return(output) }
```

however, when changing from execution environment of my_function to new_function, calling `deparse(substitute(equ))` returns `"equ"` instead of `"x+(y^2)"`

I know that the function substitute returns what was explicitly assigned to the variable. (equ) but I am wondering if there is a way for new_function() to be able to see into the execution environment of my_function() so I can get the desired output of `"x+(y^2)"`

**UPDATE**

After thinking about it, I could change what I pass to new.equ to the deparsed version of equ as follows...

```
output <- function(new.equ = EQU.sub)

new_function <- function(new.equ) { 
#given that these variables are available
value <- parse(text = new.equ)
#does some stuff....
return(output) }
```

but my original question still stands because I'm still new to R environments. Is there a more elegant way to go through execution environments?

Comment: You're missing a `)` and something else in this example so it's not directly reproducible yet. After I add the `)` it throws "object 'EQU.var.levels' not found"

Comment: @Hack-R EQU.var.levels should be gone now

Comment: `my_function` can be written like this.  `my_function <- function(data, equ) replace(data, "new.value", eval(substitute(equ), data))`

Answer (score 0):

Using non-standard evaulation like this can be pretty messy. Rather than trying to capture expressions from promises passed to functions, it's much safer just to pass a formula. For example

```
mydata <- data.frame(x=c(1,2,3,4),y=c(5,6,7,8), z=c(9,10,11,12))
my_function <- function(data, equ) {
    stopifnot(inherits(equ, "formula"))
    eval(equ[[2]], data)
}
new_function <- function(newequ) {
    my_function(mydata, newequ)
 }

my_function(mydata, ~x+(y^2))
new_function(~x+(y^2))
```

Or give your function an extra parameter where you can pass an expression instead so you don't have to rely on a promise. This makes it much easier to write other functions that can call your function.

```
my_function <- function(data, equ, .equ=substitute(equ)) {
    eval(.equ, data)
}
new_function <- function(newequ) {
     equ <- substitute(newequ)
     my_function(mydata, .equ=equ)
}

my_function(mydata, x+(y^2))
new_function(x+(y^2))
my_function(mydata, .equ=quote(x+(y^2)))
```